# How to override sass variable value in other scss file

Tags: angularjs, sass

Suppose I have a application name called MYAPP so here I want to override variable values which are present in _varialble.scss and this is imported in myapplication.scss file, So I want to override the values in new.scss file of variables mentioned in_variable.scss and I should compile this new file if I the URL is having some new parameter like mySite or something...

Comment: Personally I'd use something like Gulp and build your logic for compiling around your conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the variable again after loading the _variable.scss file. Be sure do define it before any usages though. For example your main.scss could look something like this:

myapplication.scss:

```
@import "_variables";
// overwrite your variables from _variables here in new.scss:
@import "new"
// now import the rest of your scss files where you use the variables
@import "site";
@import "module1";
// etc
```